# Taking an object from a function that has not been declared?

Tags: lua

Taking an object from a function that has not been declared?

Well, basically that's it, I need to use

```
character:removeEventListener ("touch", movePerson)
```

only that `movePerson` only happen after ... And I can not leave it for later, must be before ... would somehow ?

Asked more details, but that is almost all the information '-' It's simple: I have to draw that line up inside a function that is before movePerson function ... I think it's more confusing huh? :S

Comment: Its quite unclear what you are asking here. you will need to give a more complete example, preferably a complete self contained example showing your problem. you should also state what you expect or want to happen, and compare that with what is actually happening. If you provide that information you will probably get useful answers - if you don't this question will probably get closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it on top, and assign the function to it later, like so:

```
local character = display.newRect(200,200,200,200)
local movePerson -- This will be a reference to the function, so functions below can "see" it. 

local function addListener()
    character:addEventListener ("touch", movePerson)
end

local function removeListener()
    character:removeEventListener ("touch", movePerson) 
end

movePerson = function(event) -- Right here you declare it to the variable on top
    print(tostring(event.phase))
end

addListener()
removeListener()
```

Note that you must remove it after it has been declared, like in the example, and i don't think it is a good practice to do this, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: That way you can not because it has to be within a function that must be started before the removeMovePerson appear ...:C would have no other way?